# path dependence of the integral $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-4)^2} + \sin z$

Tags: complex-analysis

Are the integrals of the

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-4)^2} + \sin z$$

path independent in the following domain

$$D= \{\operatorname{Re} z >0\}\setminus\{4\}$$

My thought is that since $$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-4)^2} + \sin z$$ is always 0 and $\sin z$ is continuous everywhere that the integrals are path independent in the domain $$D= \{\operatorname{Re} z >0\}\setminus\{4\}$$  Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

If you can find an antiderivative $F$ of $f$ everywhere on $D$, and $f$ is continuous on $D$ and $D$ is a domain, then the contour integral along any piecewise smooth path $\gamma:[a,b] \to D$ in $D$ is simply $F(\gamma(b))-F(\gamma(a))$ by:

http://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Contour_Integration

An antiderivative for $f$ on $D$ would be $\frac{1}{4-z} - \cos (z)$.

That implies that any two smooth paths with the same start and endpoints will give the same integral.